# How to write a complex query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help on SQL queries. The Type, ProcessID and ParentProcessID are columns of a table. What I need to do is search for Type "P". Then, get it's ProcessID. Once I have it's ProcessID, I need to get all the processes of Type "S" spawned by the process of Type "P". For example:

```
Type    ProcessID   ParentProcessID
------------------------------------
P   1001049    1000052
S   1001050    1001049
S   1001051    1001049
S   1001052    1001049
S   1001053    1001049

P   1002015    1000045
S   1002016    1002015
S   1002017    1002015
S   1002018    1002015
S   1002019    1002015
```

I can write a pseudo code but I don't have any idea with SQL.

```
select * from table where Type=P...
```

...
 ...

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Mihai, I was going to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Naive solution:

```
select *
from table as Spawns
where Spawns.Type = 'S' and Spawns.ParentProcessID in (
    select Parents.ProcessID
    from table as Parents
    where Parents.Type = 'P'
)
```

Comment: I think you need to use the `Parents.ProcessID` column to map to `Spawns.ParentProcessID`, since you need to map the Spawned threads that were spawned by the threads identified in your sub-query.

Comment: @Smutje , I have another question(add as another solution) with my suggested. Any idea? Thnks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `EXISTS` to get your resultset

```
select *
from table as Spawns
where Spawns.Type = 'S' and EXISTS (
    select 1
    from table as Parents
    where Parents.Type = 'P'
    and Spawns.ParentProcessID =Parents.ProcessID   
)
```

Comment: Thank you all, I will try this. But, I want to learn more...Is this PL/SQL ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Sql Server, I like to use Common Table Expressions [(CTE)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). It can help keep different elements of the query straight.

```
With GetProcess as (

select ProcessID
from tableA
where Type = 'P')

select S.ProcessID 
from tableA S
join GetProcess P on S.processId = P.ProcessID
where S.type = 'S'
```

So, the CTE gets your processIDs where the type = P. Then, join it to your table again and find the 'S' types.